# Editing the XML Catalog in IBM RSA (Rational Software Architect)

Tags: xml, eclipse, xmlcatalog, rational-rsa

I've been working with Eclipse WTP until our organisation decided to move to IBM RSA. The problem I have is that I can't see anywhere to edit the XML Catalog in RSA (I'm using version 8.0.2).

In Eclipse WTP I used to be able to edit the XML Catalog settings via Window > Preferences > XML > XML Catalog. However in RSA I don't have the XML options (and can't figure out how to get them!).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Web Tools Platform (WTP) is included in RSA, but the XML Developer option needs to be enabled in Windows->Preferences->General->Capabilities before the XML preferences are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the IBM Installation Manager that the XML features are installed, and the Capabilities Preference page to ensure that they're enabled.